# how redirect the src from a iframe after few X seconds?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to find a Jquery script for redirecting the `src` from an iframe after a few seconds, using just a timer and happening after `x` seconds have elapsed.

Every thing I have found and tried won't work.

What I have tried:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "site";
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without jQuery. Below is an example that finds the `iframe` within the sample HTML and sets its `src` property to a web URL after 2 seconds. Please note that this function operates in milliseconds, so we're waiting 2000 milliseconds which is the same as 2 seconds.

```js
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
iframe.setAttribute('src','http://nascar.com');},2000);
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```